# How to manage asymmetric keys without checking them into source control?

Tags: google-app-engine, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a google app engine application which needs to be given a public-private key pair. I don't want to check this into source control because it will be accessible by too many people. Since this is GAE I can't use the build system to write the keys to the file system of the server.

Is there a known best practice for this? 
My first thought was does Jenkins provide a way to manage keys securely? I know I can just copy the keys to a location on the jenkins server and copy them into the build but this project will be used by third party teams so I need to provide a UI based solution in jenkins. I did not find any relevant plugin but I would like to make sure there isn't a better way before writing my own.

Comment: as you already statet, it is quite common to include the keys in a separated file and keep it outside of source-control. Most third party developers will know what a failing build with "could not include super-secret-key-file.file" means :-). As of your plugin, I havent heart of one and we use quite many here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are of course several approaches to this. I believe certificates are a concern of admins, not developers.

What we do is have [custom admin pages](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Administration_Console_Custom_Pages) where we upload certificates to blobstore under separate namespace. Then we have an internal "service" (just a simple factory) so that other pieces of code can retrieve certs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to use a cloud based Jenkins, we (CloudBees) have an oauth based solution at [appengine.cloudbees.com](https://appengine.cloudbees.com)

You could roll your own. It is not excessively tricky. You will need to

1. Register with google's api console to get a client key and secret and define the endpoints that your app will show up as
2. Write some way if feeding those credentials to your Jenkins build. I would recommend using the credentials plugin
3. Either write a build wrapper that exposes the refresh token to your build (python sdk deployment) or exposes the access token (java sdk... Got to love that the two sdks do the same thing in different ways)

Or use our free service ;-)